# Is it possible to "freeze" a version of Chrome to package with Chromedriver so I don't have to keep updating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have several scripts that utilize Selenium and Chromedriver, but having to update the chromedriver version (and re-give any related permissions) can be a pain every time Chrome comes out with a new version.

Short of disabling Chrome auto-updates, are there any solutions for this? Would love to just package a version within the venv

Comment: There is a system property to disable version checking "webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck": https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriverService.html#CHROME_DRIVER_DISABLE_BUILD_CHECK  (Not sure how you'd set that in python...) Another option is to use a service like webdriver manager... if all goes well it will detect browser version and automatically update chromedriver if necessary.

Comment: webdriver manager turns out to be even better than what I was looking for, thank you - 
PyPi link: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/